# Multithreading issues in RMI

Tags: multithreading, rmi

I am searching for issues  in RMI, especially multithreading issues 
could you help me to answer the question

the question:
What are the multithreading issues in RMI??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'multithreading issues in RMI' are that an RMI remote object (server) isn't guaranteed to be single-threaded, so you have to take care of any required synchronization within and between your remote methods yourself.